# How much silicon is required for the most common ICs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, manufacturing-process

Where can I find information about the die surface for various ICs? I'm thinking about opamps in the first place.

The surface area is of course dependent on the features of the ICs (for opamps rail to rail, speed, noise) and on the max current they can handle. 
I think the process technology affects digital electronics, but not much analog circuitry.

So, where can I find the surface area for various common ICs and especially opamps?

This is out of curiosity, I don't have a need for any project.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information? It may be in the data sheet for "COB" / bare die package, where available.

Comment: I suspect that if you have a valid need to know, that information might be available from any of the integrated circuit manufactures and foundries which manufacture die.

Comment: @EMFields, no, no manufacturers will disclose their die area sizes, this is the most sensitive business information. The answer depends on the use. If it is about integration of many OPA into a chip, the answer is "very small". If it is a stand-alone OPA, it is defined by pads area.

Comment: @AliChen, if they want to sell it to you for a COB assembly, they'd better tell you the size and pad locations.

Comment: Anyway it's hardly worth trying to keep that information secret since all their competitors have FA labs with the capability to decapsulate their parts.

Comment: @AliChen: Who have you contacted and what were the objections they mounted in order to keep you blind?

Comment: @AliChen You can get any chip you want decapped for a nominal fee. You can do it yourself too, if handling hot nitric acid doesn't faze you. Here is an [MSP430](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Decapped_MSP430F1101A.jpg)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, You can do whatever reverse engineering you want, but I would not want to make a competitor's life easy by disclosing this competitive information. First, tell me why you want to know this, and maybe we can talk. If the product is offered in die form (which sometimes happen), all info is in datasheets.

Comment: @AliChen I'm not the OP asking the question, nor do I know why they want to know. My *guess* is that die area is easy to find out (they don't bother on datasheets usually because it's unnecessary and has to be updated regularly) but *yield* is a closely held secret.

Comment: I wouldn't say die area is easy to find out, I would say it is trivially easy. An expert designer can guess it pretty well too, from the datasheet.

Comment: I would also guess that the size of stand-alone low-integration chips is limited by the size of vacuum pick-up tools on automated assembly lines.

Comment: Here's an example where the die size is actually shown in the datasheet (page 25), because the bare unpackaged dice are offered for sale: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX195.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parts that are available as bare die, this information should be in the datasheet.

Some older parts included this information even if they weren't generally available as bare die, since it might be useful for estimating reliability of the part.

For example, here's the AD621 (actually an in-amp, not an op-amp, but it was the first PN I thought of):

[image]

So, that one is about 9.1 mm<sup>2</sup>. (I dunno how they screwed up the inch measurements so badly).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the technology and the specification of the opamp and how you plan to use it. For exampe for the 741 you can find the following information.

[image]

In this case we have a complete opamp including pads. If you want use the opamp as part of a ciruit on an ASIC they are usually much smaller.

[image]